# UseEffect return statement call twice when update the state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When I click `NewTab` button, `newtab` state will change and I want to call `useEffect` when `newTab` state change, so it will `goBack()`, and will call return statement as well, but somehow return statement executing twice, with both old value and new value (false , true respectively).

Here is my problem statement.

```
const App = () => {
    const [newTab, setNewTab] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
       if (newTab) {
         navigation.goBack();
       }

        return () => { // call twice first get false, and second time get true
            if (newTab == false) {
                //clear the redux data
            }
        }
    }, [newTab]);

    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
               onPress={() => {
                  navigation.goBack();
               }}>
            GoBack
        </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                    setNewTab(true);
                    //Code for the push data in Redux store
                }}>
                NewTab
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}

export default App();
```

Comment: Are you in development mode?  See https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#my-cleanup-logic-runs-even-though-my-component-didnt-unmount

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `useEffect` in this case, your component will automatically render after state will change, like this:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [newTab, setNewTab] = useState(false);

  if (newTab) {
    navigation.goBack();
  } else{
    // Clear the redux data
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.goBack();
      }}>
        GoBack
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          setNewTab(true);
          /* Code for the push data in Redux store */
      }}>
        NewTab
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the useEffect is triggered when newTab changes, and the cleanup function is executed with the old value of newTab before the new value.
you can use a variable to store the previous value and compare it within the cleanup function.

```
const App = () => {
    const [newTab, setNewTab] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        let isMounted = true;

        if (newTab) {
            navigation.goBack();
        }

        return () => {
            if (isMounted && newTab === false) {
                // Clear the redux data
            }
            isMounted = false;
        };
    }, [newTab]);

    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                    navigation.goBack();
                }}>
                GoBack
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                    setNewTab(true);
                    // Code for pushing data into the Redux store
                }}>
                NewTab
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think setNewTab function is called with a callback that receives the previous value of newTab. This ensures that you're working with the latest state when updating newTab. The cleanup function then checks the current state to perform the necessary cleanup logic. This should also help prevent the issue of the cleanup logic being called twice with both old and new values.

```
<TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
           // Use functional update to ensure the latest state is used
            setNewTab((prevNewTab) => {
            // Code for pushing data to Redux store
                return true;
              });
        }}
  NewTab
 </TouchableOpacity>
```